# Port forwarding from Router 1 to router 2 not working?

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding

I have 2 routers.

router 1 IP : 192.168.4.1
router 2 IP : 192.168.5.1

I can easily forward port 8080 from router 1 to router 2 which routes it to a Tomcat server (port 8080 also).

I accesss this server via:

> sampleurl.com:8080

When I change to Tomcat to port 5000, and reconfigure the routers, I can access the Tomcat instance using (inside my LAN)

> TOMCAT_SERVER_IP:5000

But, accessing my Tomcat from outside doesn't seem to work at all! I just changed the port and it doesn't work anymore:

> sampleurl.com:5000

I installed Wireshark on the server and using the URL above does trigger anything (so the server is not being hit). I've tripled checked port forwarding...

Is there a magic trick or something special to do to use any port other then 8080?

Thank you!

Comment: Found my problem, seems DDWRT was "bugging a bit" since I cleared the ports being forwarded (which were only 3 and all but on disabled). Everything is now working as expected.

Comment: Please post an answer to your own question, and then accept it, so that this question can be categorized as resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, this DD-WRT is not forwarding the ports correctly. I found that this obscure bug can occur but since I do not want to fiddle anymore with my router I just forwarded all ports to the same host. Not very clean but I'm just making tests.